# how do I I get quarter one from this array?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript.  This is my lesson from school, but it is not working for me.

```
var region1 = [1540, 1130, 1580, 1105];
var region2 = [2010, 1168, 2305, 4102];
var region3 = [2450, 1847, 2710, 2391];
var region4 = [1845, 1491, 1284, 1575];
var region5 = [2120, 1767, 1599, 3888];
```

how do I add up for q1? Quarter one is the first value in each array

Comment: i dont understand what you need.

Comment: What are you talking about? Do you mean [quartile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile)?

Comment: I need to create a variable that adds up quarter one

Comment: Why don't you create an array of arrays instead of defining a new variable for each array?

Comment: Dear All, I was showing a friend how to use stack overflow to help her learn JavaScript.  It was very helpful. Thank You.  But I will Delete this question now.

Comment: It's still not clear if you want to sum the first value of each array, create an array with them, or whatever.

Comment: Just a note for your friend: this is not how to use StackOverflow. Do some research first, show your attempt, and fully explain the issue you're having.

Comment: Another first reaction is .... *"but it is not working for me"*....What's not working...show the code attempt

Answer (score 1):

This adds up the first entry from each array and stores it into a variable called `q1`.

```
for ( var regions = [], i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) 
    regions.push( eval( 'region' + i ) );
var q1 = regions.reduce( ( sum, region ) => sum + region[0] , 0 );

console.log( q1 ); // 9965
```

Comment: Using eval is pretty nasty...

Comment: @user3183526 Not in this case. It is the quickest and easiest way to access each of those variables that are named `regionX`. It's also safe, since there is no user input and you can see in advance exactly what the eval'd strings will be.

Comment: Eval is actually really slow, performance wise. Generally it's just seen as not a good thing to use... Also, if there is only 5 regions at a time then it would probably be better to just hardcode it i.e `region1[0] + region2[0] . . .`, or seek an alternative input format.

Comment: @user3183526 `eval` is slow sometimes, it depends on what is passed in. I doubt it is slow to eval a single identifier. It is generally seen as a bad practice to use `eval`, but there are certain cases that call for it, and if the OP has input in the form of several variables like he shows, instead of an array, eval is the most flexible way to convert it to a better format, like a single array of regions. The code is flexible, because whether there are five regionXs or 500, you only need to change the length of the loop, but hardcoding the sum would need each variable to be manually appended.